# How to do a search in a line to a specific point

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, line

I'm using QGIS 2.0.1 Dufour. I'm working with a shape file made by a single line that represents a road with 30km. In that line I want to attach pdf files containing information about some points in that road. I would like to be able to do a search like: 'km = 2,300' and find the files with the information about that point. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at [linear referencing](http://www.faunalia.eu/en/lrs.html) tools in QGIS. You can create an event on the road based on 'km=2' then select by location around this event.